# Why are these equivleant expression trees returning different sql?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, lambda, expression-trees

I have two expressions that I'm using for a global query filter on my entity project.

I have the following compile time one:

```
Expression<Func<RandomTable, bool>> test = c => AuthorisedUsers.Any(b => b.RandomTableId == c.RandomTableId && b.UserId == UserId);
```

AuthorisedUsers is a List which contains a simple structure of a userid and randomtableid to ensure people who are accessing RandomTable have been authorised in the authorisedusers table which is a 1-m table. A user can have access to many RandomTables

The above expression creates the following SQL which is **perfect**

```
SELECT *
FROM [RandomTable] AS [h]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [AuthorisedUsers] AS [p0]
    WHERE ([p].[ID] = [p0].[RandomTableId]) AND ([p0].[UserId] = @__userId_0))
```

But then I have created the same expression at runtime using a lambdaexpression but for every table in my dbcontext. However the same expression then creates this sql instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM [RandomTable] AS [h]
WHERE EXISTS (
 SELECT 1               <-- Why are we querying this to then query it again below?
    FROM [AuthorisedUsers] AS [p] <-- 
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [AuthorisedUsers] AS [p0]
        WHERE ([p0].[RandomTableId] = [p].[RandomTableId]) AND ([p0].[UserId] = @__ef_filter__GetUserId_1)) AND (([p].[RandomTableId] = [h].[RandomTableId]) AND ([p].[UserId] = @__ef_filter__GetUserId_0)))
```

As we can see on the above query it seems to pointlessly query the AuthorisedUsers to then query it again and then apply the correct where clause. I can't figure out why the lambda expression used by entity would translate into a unneeded sub select.

If I examine the expression of both these expressions in the debugger(debug view for both expressions) we can see their identical except for one minor difference but I don't believe it would have this effect? I have put 2** next to the underlying differences that I can see but aside from that it seems to be it should 100% generate the exact same SQL?

Appreciate any help on this!

---------------------BAD SQL Debug Results--------------------

Debug Evaluation:

```
{x => value(DbContext).AuthorisedUsers.Any(b => ((b.RandomTableId == x.RandomTableId) AndAlso (b.UserId == value(DbContext).UserId)))}  **System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression {System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1<System.Func<Entities.RandomTable, bool>>}**
```

DebugView:

```
 .Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Entities.RandomTable,System.Boolean]>(Entities.RandomTable$x)
    {
        .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Any(
            .Constant<DbContext>(DbContext).AuthorisedUsers,
            '(.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[Entities.AuthorisedUsers,System.Boolean]>))
    }

.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[Entities.AuthorisedUsers,System.Boolean]>(Entities.AuthorisedUsers$b)
{
    $b.RandomTableId == $x.RandomTableId && $b.UserId == .Constant<DbContext>(DbContext).UserId
}
```

---------------------Good SQL Debug Results--------------------

Debug Evaluation:

```
 {c => value(DbContext).AuthorisedUsers.Any(b => ((b.RandomTableId == c.RandomTableId) AndAlso (b.UserId == value(DbContext).UserId)))} **System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Entities.RandomTable, bool>> {System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1<System.Func<Entities.RandomTable, bool>>}**
```

DebugView:

```
 .Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Entities.RandomTable,System.Boolean]>(Entities.RandomTable $c)
    {
        .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Any(
            .Constant<DbContext>(DbContext).AuthorisedUsers,
            '(.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[Entities.AuthorisedUsers,System.Boolean]>))
    }
    
    .Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[Entities.AuthorisedUsers,System.Boolean]>(Entities.AuthorisedUsers $b)
    {
        $b.RandomTableId == $c.RandomTableId && $b.UserId == .Constant<DbContext>(DbContext).UserId
    }
```

Expressions are applied like so in dbcontext:

```
      foreach (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IMutableEntityType entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(et => et.BaseType == null))
            {
//Done like this to compare the same expression(hand built vs runtime) //in debugger
       if (entityType.ClrType == typeof(RandomTable))
                    {
                        entityType.SetQueryFilter(test);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    entityType.SetQueryFilter(testruntimeversion);
                    }

}
```

If we use the expression visualizer debug tool it translates BOTH expressions to the same how does this make any sense?!

```
(Entities.RandomTable c) => ProviderAccess.Any<Entities.AuthorisedUsers>(

    // Quoted to induce a closure:
    (Entities.AuthorisedUsers _) => (b.RandomTableId == c.RandomTableId) && (b.UserId == UserId))
```

Bad expression creation:

```
 //The below Expression Tree is equiv to the lambda:
                Expression<Func<RandomTable, bool>> test = c => AuthorisedUsers.Any(b => b.RandomTableId == c.RandomTableId && b.UserId == GetUserId);

            ParameterExpression b = Expression.Parameter(typeof(AuthorisedUsers), "b");
            ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "x");

            MethodInfo anymethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Single(mi => mi.Name == "Any" && mi.GetParameters().Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(AuthorisedUsers));
            MemberExpression localUserId = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Constant(this), typeof(DbContext).GetProperty(nameof(GetUserId), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public));

            MemberExpression getAuthorisedUsers = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
                        Expression.Constant(this), typeof(DbContext).GetProperty(nameof(AuthorisedUsers)));

            MemberExpression randomtableid = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(b, typeof(AuthorisedUsers).GetProperty("RandomTableId"));

            MemberExpression userid = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(b, typeof(AuthorisedUsers).GetProperty("UserId"));

            BinaryExpression randomTableIdmatch = Expression.Equal(randomtableid,
                                     Expression.Convert(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(x, entityType.ClrType.GetProperty(propertyName)), typeof(int)));

            LambdaExpression g = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(anymethod, getAuthorisedUsers,
                                   Expression.Quote(
                                       Expression.Lambda(Expression.AndAlso(randomTableIdmatch,
                                       Expression.Equal(userid, localUserId)
                                   ), b)
                           )
                       ),
                       x
                   );
```

entityType.SetQueryFilter(g);

Comment: Probably only Microsoft guys can read Debug View output. Install [ReadableExpressions.Visualizers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1232914.ReadableExpressionsVisualizers) and update answer with visualised expressions.

Comment: Also post how do you apply filters and to which entities.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I've installed it and compared both expressions. Unfortunately they're exactly the same.  Really hoped this was the missing piece!                                                                               `(Entities.RandomTable c) => ProviderAccess.Any<Entities.AuthorisedUsers>(

    // Quoted to induce a closure:
    (Entities.AuthorisedUsers _) => (b.RandomTableId == c.RandomTableId) && (b.UserId == UserId))`

Comment: Have you checked the execution plans for the two queries? That's what you should care about. So long as two queries express the same *logical* requirements, they *should* produce identical plans even if the original SQL is structured differently

Comment: Fair point, just checked the actual execution plan and unfortunately they are different(two extra steps)

Comment: Try my [ExpressionTreeToString](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeToString) using the Textual Tree rendering, or [Expression Tree Visualizer](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeVisualizer) which allows you to see the precise structure of the expression tree. See [here](https://github.com/simple-odata-client/Simple.OData.Client/issues/638#issuecomment-512890629) for a similar comparison between two supposedly equivalent expression trees.

Comment: Moreover, the above library can provide you with the calls to the factory methods on `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` which will recreate the same expression tree (using the "Factory methods" [renderer](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeToString/wiki/Available-renderers)).

Comment: I actually love your extension! Used in the past but forgot about it since upgrading vs. Compared and still 1:1 which makes it all more weird that entity is interpreting it differently oh well I suppose(Compared both variables with factory method)

Comment: Use "Textual tree" you may get something different. Apropos the factory methods renderer: I've just looked at the code and it **doesn't** include the delegate type as an argument to `Lambda()` (unless it's not a `Func<>` or `Action<>`), which based on your question is a bug.

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to create the bad expression?

Comment: Yes will post code in a few mins. Just compared textual tree but no difference either

Comment: Added expression creation to bottom of post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247988/discussion-between-rudimentalghost-and-zev-spitz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bad expression tree uses [**LambdaExpression**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression) which is the base type for [**Expression<TDelegate>**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression-1) (used by your good expression tree). **LambdaExpression** represents a lambda expression which isn't strongly typed, unlike **Expression<TDelegate>**.

If you want your constructed expression tree to have **Expression<TDelegate>** you should use one of the [overloads of **Expression.Lambda**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda?view=net-6.0#system-linq-expressions-expression-lambda(system-type-system-linq-expressions-expression-system-linq-expressions-parameterexpression())) which takes a delegate type.

NB. The difference is not visible in DebugView, but see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/debugview-syntax) for DebugView syntax

Comment: This was spot on. I had to specify the strongly typed for it to translate to sql correctly. Thanks a lot, really thought this was a lost cause :D